# Problem Changing the Imagesource via a Static Class

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

I have this very annoying bug that i encounter in every project:

I have a class (same namespace) where i store references to Images like this:

```
public class Res
{
     public static BitmapImage A = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images\A.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

When i try to change the source of an element towards one of these static references via:

```
xamldefinedimage.Source = Res.A;
```

it does absolutely nothing. (I enclose it of course with the corresponding Dispatcher.)

Now when i assign the image source like this:

```
xamldefinedimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images\A.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

it works just fine. I checked the images Properties (Ressource, Copy on Build -> look ok).

This problem drives me especially nuts because i have older projects where the reference setting works just fine. I dont want to use a workaround but a special class with static references to keep the code minimal. I really want to get to the bottom of this and understand what i am missing here once and for all. This is basically a blank project, not much has been done yet. What is the issue here, what are potential reasons the first approach is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about static class but you did not defined Res class as static.

your code should be like this :

```
public static class Res
{
 public static BitmapImage A = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images\A.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Also if your images are in the App Resources then your class should be like this :

```
public static class Res
{
 public static BitmapImage A = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/A.png"));
}
```

Comment: Indeed making the class static fixed it for good. Thanks a lot!